# Returning a const std::map<std::string, const std::shared_ptr<Object const>> in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map that looks like this: `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Object>>`

I need to create a method in a class that will ensure the map and its contents are read-only.

Is there a way to define a method that will return something like this: `const std::map<std::string, const std::shared_ptr<Object const>>` without modifying the original definition of the map or creating a copy of it?

I need the returned map to be constant, the `std::shared_ptr` to be constant, and the underlying `Object` to be constant

I'm not sure how to define the method in a way that returns a const map with const values.

Comment: May I ask why you need this? I think it cannot be done safely, but even if it can, one could modify the Object with const_cast.

Comment: You can provide a const interface to a non-const map.

Comment: Do what @n.m.couldbeanAI suggests. Don't return a copy of, or a reference to, the map. Provide member functions to query the map without changing it.

Comment: Agreed. Once you hand out direct access to an object, they can basically do whatever they want with that object. If you don't want that, then don't hand it out directly. Wrap it in an interface, and then control what that interface can and can't do.

Comment: As @RemyLebeau said -- I'd wrap that map in an object that exposes the const semantics.  Add access by index etc. and return rather than the `std::shared_ptr<T>` a `const T*`

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll find the (experimental) [propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) useful.  When accessing a const-qualified pointer, or anything that behaves like one, it makes the pointee const.

Here is how you would use it:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/propagate_const>

struct Object
{
    int get_something() const { return 0; };
    int set_something() { return 1; };
};

class Demo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    using prop_const = std::experimental::propagate_const<T>;
    using map_type = std::map<std::string, prop_const<std::shared_ptr<Object>>>;

    map_type const& get_const_map() const { return the_map; }
    map_type& get_map() { return the_map; }

private:
    map_type the_map;
};

int main()
{
    std::string const key{ "A" };
    Demo demo;
    demo.get_map()[key] = std::make_shared<Object>();

    demo.get_map().at(key)->set_something(); // OK: mutable access
    demo.get_const_map().at(key)->get_something(); // OK: const access
    //demo.get_const_map()[key]->set_something(); // Error: requires non-const access (*)
}
```

On line (*), GCC 13 gives the following error, if commented out:

```
<source>:36:29: error: passing 'const Demo::map_type' {aka 'const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<Object> > >'} as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   36 |     demo.get_const_map()[key]->set_something(); // Error: requires non-const access
      |                             ^
```

Comment: Actually implementing it on one's own is also pretty simple, despite some boilerplate involved; adding an example implementation would be really nice.

Answer (score -1):

As `shared_ptr<Object>` and `shared_ptr<Object const>` are 2 different types, this idea doesn't sound so safe. Here's an example how things could go wrong:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
};


template <>
struct Foo<int>
{
    int i;

    Foo():
        i{12}
    {}

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

};


template <>
struct Foo<int const>
{
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Ooops!" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct Bar
{
    std::map<std::string, Foo<int>> map;

    std::map<std::string, Foo<int>> & get()
    {
        return map;
    }

    std::map<std::string, Foo<int const>> const & const_get()
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<std::map<std::string, Foo<int const>> *>(&map);
    }

    Bar()
    {
        map["a"];
    }
};


int main()
{
    Bar b;
    {
        auto & foo = b.get().at("a");
        std::cout << b.get().at("a").i << std::endl; // 12
        foo.print(); // 12
    }
    {
        auto & foo = b.const_get().at("a");
        // std::cout << b.const_get().at("a").i << std::endl; // Compilation error
        foo.print(); // Ooops!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the actual question that was asked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, the question was how to return a map with `shared_ptr<Object const>` values without copying. That's the only way I can think of (ugly as hell), but of course I'm happy to learn if anyone willing to share other method.